# keras.models import Sequential

Tags: import, ipython, theano, keras, sequential

on typing the line

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

in `ipython` , I got the following error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6mUu.png)

Both the `Theano` and `Keras` library are installed and updated. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could improve your question by including the text of your error in your post (not just a screenshot).

Comment: Could you provide the error message? there is no error visible in the screenshot.